# Objective C - navigation button without animation but with option to Perform back

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm kind new in all the Objective C stuff so try to understand :)

i want to use a navigation button to move to the next view but without any animation.

and i need to save the Current info in the source view and be able to have back button in the destination view.

in modal style i can't save my info and when i'm back to the screen all the info disappeared.

in push style i can use the back button but i cant stop the animation.

in custom style i didn't make it either

help?

btw - please try to give specific answer so i can understand :) THNKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having navigation controller you can easily do this by pusing `viewController` to current navigation stack. If you don't want to navigate with an animation you can pass `NO` to animated value like this.
`[self.navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:NO];` If you want pass `YES`.

Now when ever you will push view controller you will get a back button, its navigation controller duty to create it for you. Title of this button will be same as source view `controller` `title`, if there is no `title` button title will be back.

Now how you can do that, add a button to your source view controller and assign an action. Call this code in action of that button.

You can add button by interface builder and can set action by clt+drag to source file. Or you can add that button by code.

if you want to do it by code add this in `viewDidLoadMethod`

```
UIButton *next = [UIButton alloc] init];
[next setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then add btnClicked method in

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender{
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
Second* controller= (Second*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
  [self.navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
}
```

**Edit** 
It would be better first you go to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1) and read some basics.

Comment: Thank. i dont understand what "controller" mean.
i wrote it like that :

SecondPage *Second = [[SecondPage alloc]init];
    
[self.navigationController] pushViewController:Second.navigationController animated:NO];

but then i see error "Expected identifier"

Comment: If the second is viewController you can do like this 
 `[self.navigationController] pushViewController:Second animated:NO];`

Comment: same error again =\      "Expected identifier". maybe im doing something else wrong?

Comment: Can you explain how you are creating viewController, do you have stroyboard...?

Comment: Yes of course. in the stroyboard i have 2 views "A" is the main and "B" is the second. i wrote "import B.h" in A.m and connected them with push segue. do i need to do or have anything else?

Comment: See the updated code, You must set identifier for a viewcontroller in storyboard...

Comment: Thnaks. i know what is identifier. i have an identifier on the connections between the views already. i really dont know what's the problem.. =\

Comment: Are you creating segue... or you have just view controllers in storyboard...?

Comment: mmm.. i'm not sure, what you mean by "creating segue"?

btw - now i tried this code and the animation is gone but i see black screen insted the second view:

[self presentViewController : Second animated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: Edit you question by updating latest code and if possible also add screen shot of storyboard...

Comment: it's a very simple storyboard. i don't have much code because all i want to do is cancel the animation and be able to use the back button. this is the SB if it's help : http://jan.imghost.us/4doC.png

Comment: Its means you are using segue... you don't need a code in push button, becacue you had create a segue from button to the next view controller, when that button will push your second viewcontroller will be push automatically. Now you got two options 1.delete that segue/connection between push button to next view controller and leave your code as it is... 2. Implement your custom segue and for that you can read this tutorial. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH16-SW1

Comment: Thanks man. it's still don't want to work. i'm sure that this is my fault and i'm doing something wrong. hope that i'll learn more in the future and will make it work :)

Comment: can you maybe create a simple project with two views one with push (or whatever) without animation and the second with back button and send it to me? that can be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UINavigationController to posh/pop all your view controllers. You can control the animation using

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:(NO)];
```

or

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:controller animated:(NO)];
```

I hope that helps. Here is a tutorial on using UINavigationController

http://bharanijayasuri.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/simple-uinavigationcontroller-tutorial-2/

Comment: where do i need to put these methods? in the button or in viewDidAppear ?

and how do i call to the second view? do i need to create an instance ?

Comment: crate actions on your next/back button and link them to your view controller. Place the above code in the actions implementation.